# How to pass date from DateTimePicker to api

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a DateTimePicker and I want it to get mapped with this api key `("last_date": "2022-07-09")`. The `DateTimePicker` is shown below:

```
Stack(
              children: <Widget>[
                DateTimePicker(
                  initialValue: '',
                  firstDate: DateTime(2000),
                  lastDate: DateTime(2100),
                  dateLabelText: 'Date',
                  onChanged: (val) => print(val),
                  validator: (val) {
                    print(val);
                    return null;
                  },
                  onSaved: (val) => print(val),
                )
              ],
            ),
```

Comment: Are you using null safety? so I can share a relevant code.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on what it is you want to do? Do you just want to save the value chosen in the datetimepicker with the key last_date?

Comment: @ShahzadUmarBaig yes I'm using null safety

Comment: @tomerpacific I want to save the value and pass it to api

Comment: What API is this? Where is it located in your project?

Comment: @tomerpacific I have the REST API endpoint and I want to map and pass the date selected to it

Comment: Please provide the code that is responsible for making this request and how you call it. Basically, you need to create a JSON object and convert it to a string and send it in your request.

Answer (score 0):

Make a variable in your class:

```
late DateTime selectedDate;

@override
initState((){
super.initState();
selectedDate = DateTime.now();
});

... // all the boilerplate and then your stack widget
           Stack(
              children: <Widget>[
                DateTimePicker(
                  initialValue: selectedDate,
                  firstDate: DateTime(2000),
                  lastDate: DateTime(2100),
                  dateLabelText: 'Date',
                  onChanged: (val) => setState(() => selectedDate = val),
                  validator: (val) {
                    print(val);
                    return null;
                  },
                  onSaved: (val) => setState(() => selectedDate = val),
                )
              ],
            ),
```

This way you will be saving your DateTimePicker value into a variable, once that is done then you can alter the DateTime value using two different method

**METHOD #1**

```
// When you call this function, make sure you pass the variable we declared earlier into this function parameters

String modifyDateTime(DateTime selectedDate){
 return selectedDate.year.toString() + " - "+ selectedDate.month.toString()
      + "-" + selectedDate.day.toString();
}

// This function will return your selected date in this format "Y-M-D"
```

**METHOD 2**

You can use intl package from pub.dev, https://pub.dev/packages/intl. Where you can declare DateFormat variable as such:

```
DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat("y-M-d");

// you can use the this format variable as such

dateFormat.format(selectedDate);

// This will return you a String in your desired format
```

And finally now you can construct a Map body for your API

```
Map ApiBody = {
"late_date": selectedDate,
};
```

Which you can pass into your API. I hope this answers your question.